# Only Workdays and Remove Weekends

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my A column, I am having entire month dates. Now I want to remove all weekends and only keep workdays meaning only Monday to Friday.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A2:A, TEXT(A2:A, "ddd")<>"sat",
                           TEXT(A2:A, "ddd")<>"sun"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

in one go it would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&DATE(2019, 1, 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(2019, 1, 1), 0)))), TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&DATE(2019, 1, 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(2019, 1, 1), 0)))), "ddd")<>"sat", TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&DATE(2019, 1, 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(2019, 1, 1), 0)))), "ddd")<>"sun"), "dd-mmm-yyyy"))
```

[image: 0]

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&        DATE(2019, 1, 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(2019, 1, 1), 0)))), REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&        DATE(2019, 1, 1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(DATE(2019, 1, 1), 0)))), "ddd"),"Sat|Sun","♠")<>"♠"), "dd-mmm-yyyy"))
```